# How to notate a sequence of decimals

Tags: notation

I would like to know if there is a mathematically correct way of describing a sequence of decimal points of a given number.

e.g. position 35-46 of π

Comment: there is no such notation. You are free to make up anything you want.

Comment: Thats too bad. But thank you!

Comment: @awk There's no simple notation, but using the floor notation you can write a formula for it, see my answer given below.

Comment: have you thought about continued fractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using "floor", the integer part of a number, indicated by $\lfloor x\rfloor$?  So $\pi - \lfloor\pi\rfloor$ is the decimal part of $\pi$. So $\lfloor (\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor) * 10^{46} \rfloor$ would give you the first $46$ decimal places.  So $\left\lfloor(30{\Large(}(\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor)-\lfloor30(\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor)\rfloor{\Large)} * 16\right\rfloor$ would give you places $35$ to $46$.  I think.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for thank you!

Would $\lfloor (\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor) * 10^{46} \rfloor$ - $\lfloor (\pi-\lfloor\pi\rfloor) * 10^{35} \rfloor$ be the same?

Comment: @awk It would be close, but it would have a bunch of trailing zeros.  So divide by $10^{35}$

Comment: Wouldn't the zeroes be at the front like 00000123?

Comment: @awk Actually we're both wrong, you would have to multiply the second term by $10^{16}$ before subtracting, then you would still have the trailing zeros so divide the whole thing by $10^{16}$ again.

Comment: @awk I had some missing parentheses as I originally stated it, but I think it's right now.

Answer (score 1):

In theoretical computer science, the notation $u[i,j]$ is frequently used to denote the factor $a_ia_{i+1} \dots a_j$ of an infinite word $u = a_0a_1 \dotsm$.
Considering a number as an infinite word on the alphabet $\{0, \dotsm, 9\}$, you could adapt this notation and write something like $\pi[35,46]$. The obvious problem is the radix point, but you could work on the alphabet $\{0, \dotsm, 9, .\}$ instead and define the position of the radix point as $0$. With these conventions, for the real number $r = \sqrt{54321} = 233.068659412 \dotsm$, you could write $r[-2,6]= 33.068659$.

Answer (score 1):

This might be best approached by carefully doing a small example.  Suppose we'd like to capture the $926$ in $\pi=3.1415{\color\red{926}}5\ldots$.  Note that $10^4\pi=31415.9265\ldots$, hence

$$10^4\pi-\lfloor10^4\pi\rfloor=0.9265\ldots$$

and thus

$$926=\lfloor10^3\cdot0.9265\ldots\rfloor=\lfloor10^7\pi-10^3\lfloor10^4\pi\rfloor\rfloor$$

For the specific example the OP mentioned, i.e. decimal positions 35-46, it should be clear the answer has the form

$$\lfloor10^n\pi-10^{12}\lfloor10^{n-12}\pi\rfloor\rfloor$$

where $n$ is either $45$ or $46$, depending on whether you count decimal positions starting at the $3$ or not.  (I.e., does $926$ correspond to decimal positions 6-8 or 5-7?)